# How to load the start point and end point in Google map?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I have integrated Google map in my application with routes but I am getting only the end point loaded. I am unable to load the start point and the middle points.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php $final_input_string = ''; ?>
            <?php foreach ($riderRoute as $rider) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php $currentTime = Yii::$app->Common->formatDateOnlyUS($rider->currentTime); ?>
                    <td><?php echo $currentTime; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rider->lat; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rider->lng; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo $rider->lat; ?>,<?php echo $rider->lng; ?>&zoom=14&size=600x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&language=&markers=color:red|label:none|<?php echo $rider->lat; ?>,<?php echo $rider->lng; ?>"  width="400" height="180" style="border:1px solid #CECECE;"> </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <?php $final_input_string = ($final_input_string == '') ? $final_input_string . $rider->lat . ',' . $rider->lng : $final_input_string . '|' . $rider->lat . ',' . $rider->lng; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <td><div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div></td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
            var map = null;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var markers = [
            <?php 
            $long = $rider->lng;
            $lat = $rider->lat;
            $routes = array("lng" => $long, "lat" => $lat);
            $route_points = array($routes);
            foreach ($route_points as $points) {
            ?>
                    {
                    "lat": <?php echo "'" . $points['lat'] . "'"; ?>,
                    "lng": <?php echo "'" . $points['lng'] . "'"; ?>,
                    },
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            ];
            window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[0].lat),
                    parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
            minZoom: 1, 
            maxZoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var lat_lng = new Array();
                    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            title: data.title
                    });
                    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                    (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    })(marker, data);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
                    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
                    //***********ROUTING****************//

                    //Intialize the Path Array
                    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
                    //Intialize the Direction Service
                    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    //Set the Path Stroke Color
                    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({map: map, strokeColor: '#4986H7'});
                    //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
                    for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
            var src = lat_lng[i];
                    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                    path.push(src);
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    service.route({
                    origin: src,
                            destination: des,
                            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                    path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                    }
                    });
            }
            }
            }
</script>
```

And my output:

[image]